# Is it possible that after upgrading python, all previously installed third-party modules will automatically become available in the new version?

Tags: python, windows-10, python-module

I have been using Python 3.8.3 for a while now and over time I have installed many third-party modules. I just recently installed python 3.10.0 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and after doing so, while working on a project, I tried to import **pygame** but it gave me this error message:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Is there a way that I can upgrade python to a new version without having to re-download all my already installed packages through:

```
pip freeze --path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages > requirements.txt

pip install -r requirements.pip
```

I also want to know if the following will work:

1. Copying the ***site-packages*** folder from *C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages*
2. Pasting it in my *C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib* directly.
3. Retrying the import statement mentioned above

I am working on a *windows 10 pc*